# How to disable removing unused imports?

Tags: go, ide, goland, goimports

I use `goimports` to automatically reformat my code and make it clean and also keep import in order. But sometimes it works in an incomfortable way together with IDE autosave. Like in this scenario:

1. I want to add new package to my code.
2. Then I install it with `dep ensure` and refresh my IDE cache.
3. I can comfortably use the package with IDE autocomplete and navigation.

What happens with `goimports` and IDE?

1. I add new package
2. In order to run `dep ensure` I have to save a file
3. `goimports` finds unused package and removes it from imports. Not good.

Workaround:

A. Add new package manually with `dep ensure -add %packagename%`

B. Disable `goimports` and move to `gofmt` - so-so.

C. Do not autoformat code on save - undesirable.

How to setup things more convenient?

P.S. Unsure about tag `godeps` but `DEP` is definitly wrong here.

Comment: "goimports finds unused package and removes it from imports." Then simply use the package before saving. The "normal" action would be to just add code like `fancypkg.DoStuff()` and have goimports add `import "wherever.com/whatnot/fancypkg"`. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it, but it's also not very convenient - I have to type something before save, then `dep ensure` then refresh, then type normal way.

Comment: Well, adding new 3rd party packages is not _that_ common and should be taken serious, so I doubt this "inconvenience" does matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution would be to invoke `dep ensure -add package/name` yourself and then just start using the package without manually importing it, the IDE will figure out that you want to use that package and will add the import automatically. The current behavior you are experiencing is exactly what's expected from the IDE since `goimports` is invoked on save and because the import is not used it will be automatically removed.